# How to upload the file to s3 without HTML form in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, amazon-s3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am  having application where user can record their voices via flash player, and then I am creating a mp3 file from the Bytes array string coming from the flash player. Now I want to upload the mp3 file in to S3. Anybody's help would be really appreciated.

Comment: have you looked into paperclip and s3?

Comment: No I think paperclip can upload file from HTML form, but I want to upload the file which was dynamically created from the byte array string from the Flash player

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [aws-s3 gem](https://github.com/marcel/aws-s3) or [fog](http://fog.io/1.7.0/index.html) to handle this.

Example with `aws-s3` :

```
AWS::S3::Base.establish_connection!(
  :access_key_id     => 'abc', 
  :secret_access_key => '123'
)

file = 'black-flowers.mp3'
S3Object.store(file, open(file), 'bucketname')
```

For an example with `fog`, see [here](http://fog.io/0.8.1/storage/)

Answer (score 0):

The gem to be used is aws-s3 0.6.2

```
AWS::S3::Base.establish_connection!(:access_key_id => 'key', :secret_access_key => 'secret_key')
```

This establishes the connection. You can write the mp3 as,

```
AWS::S3::S3Object.store('my_mp3s/name.mp3', open(Rails.root.join('tmp', 'old.mp3'), 'bucket_name')
```

The first argument is where in the bucket you would like to store the mp3, second argument is the actual file content, third one being the actual bucket in which you would like to store